# Columnwise Multiplication of Pandas Dataframe with Series (missmatched indices)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use python's pandas for some simple matrix calculation and encountered one problem when trying to do the following simple multiplication:

```
df = df.mul(column, axis=1)
```

df is one 3x3 dataframe and  looks like:

```
                    441090707  441090801  441090408
        441090408   0.255061   0.202650   0.689114
        441090707   0.287952   0.218351   0.116750
        441090801   0.456987   0.578998   0.194136
```

while column is one series which looks like:

```
            area
            441090707     179.727362
            441090801     698.939741
            441090408    1377.909774
            Name: Test, dtype: float64
```

The multiplication throws a RuntimeWarning ('<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects) and returns the following:

```
                       441090707  441090801    ...      441090801  441090408
        441090408        NaN        NaN    ...            NaN        NaN
        441090707        NaN        NaN    ...            NaN        NaN
        441090801        NaN        NaN    ...            NaN        NaN
```

As the documentation states "Mismatched indices will be unioned together", so there seems to be a problem with my index.
But I can't figure out how to make the series-indices match the dataframe- columns.

(The multiplication worked when I used "column.values", but this is not a solution because the order of the series might change)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Can you add pandas version and a minimal code snippet to reproduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas uses numpy under the hood, so you can just simply multiply them as matrices. Using a dummy case:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':[7,8,9]})
cl=pd.Series([1,2,3])
ans=df.values @ cl
```

You just have to use `values` to get the 2d numpy array.

**EDIT**

So the top part is not really what you wanted. You want an elementwise multiplication, but the problem is that the indexes of your dataframe and series have different order. Since using `values` has worked, then I take that means you have the same number of indexes and no index is missing. You just simply need to `reindex` your column

```
ans=df.mul(cl.reindex(df.index).values,axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, but if using df.values, I have to depend on the columns being in the correct order. If some columns are ordered incorrectly, the results won’t make sense. That’s why I am using pandas in the first place

Comment: I see, so what you want is elementwise multiplication?

Comment: Yes, every element of one column (from the dataframe) should be multiplied by the same value in the series (so a matching of df-columns and series-index)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I only had a change to test it out right now. It is working. Thank you a lot